# Understandng the reason for recv blocking forever

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I run a Linux program written in C that would periodically receive data by parsing an HTTP response, crunch some numbers and then report the result by HTTP GET of another web page.

My problem is that sometimes, one of the instances would "freeze".

Looking at `top` I can see that it is in `sk_wait_data` state and attaching a debugger reveals that it is blocked by a `recv` call.

Here is a minimal version of the code that does the TCP connection (it was adapted from http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm):

```c
int connectTCP(const char* host, const char* page, int portno) {
    int sockfd;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    // Create socket //
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");


    // Get ip from hostname //
    server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL)
        error("ERROR, can not find host\n");

    memset((char *) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));


    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy((char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,   // Destination
            (char *)server->h_addr,  // Source
            server->h_length);       // Size
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    // Conect to socket //
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");

    return sockfd;

}

char* httpGet(const char* host, const char* page, int portno) {
  int sockfd, n;

  sockfd = connectTCP(host, page, portno);
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

  sprintf(buffer, "GET /%s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", page, host);

  n = send(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer), 0);

  if (n < 0) 
    error("ERROR writing to socket");

  int count = 0;
  do {
    n = recv(sockfd, buffer + count, BUFFER_MAX_SIZE - count, 0);
    if (n < 0) {
      error("ERROR reading from socket");

    }

    count += n;
  } while(n != 0);

  close(sockfd);

  return buffer;
}
```

Comment: What happens if the page is bigger than the buffer?

Comment: What happens if the first recv() returns fewer bytes than the GET send string that still lies in the buffer?

Comment: You need to debug more, or show how your html parsing and buffer management work, or both.

Comment: Also, the example code in your link sucks.  T start wiht, it has the annoying cargo-cult  'bzero(buffer,256);' in it, and probably more issues further down.  You should be aware that there are many lame, sucky, bad and/or downright wrong server<>client examples on the net:(

Comment: @MartinJames Under normal operation, page is several bytes and should not be bigger than the buffer (100k). If there is a server error, page is reporting the stack trace and could be bigger, but not bigger than 100k. Regarding second comment, I don't think it is the source of my current problem, but is indeed something I should fix.

Comment: Despite everybody saying recv returns immediately if there is data available, I can reproduce this issue exactly on Linux. recv just blocks even if send on the other side returns.

Answer (score 0):

Bugs in your code:

1. If `recv()` returns zero you whould close the socket and stop reading.
2. If `recv()` returns -1 you should report the error, close the socket, and stop reading, unless you had set a read timeout and `errno` was EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK, in which case you should handle the timeout however is appropriate for your application.

Comment: Why #1 is a bug? I was thinking that if recv returns 0, there is no more data to read and I can close socker and return the buffer. Regarding #2, I do report an error in the error function and exit the program. I am not sure I understand what you wrote about EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK...